# Issue with Postgres DB and Celery - DB_PAGE_NOTFOUND: Requested page not found

Tags: python, postgresql, celery

```
 File "/opt/tomigo/virtualenvs/tomigo_core/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 112, in start_scheduler
beat.start()
File "/opt/tomigo/virtualenvs/tomigo_core/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 453, in start
humanize_seconds(self.scheduler.max_interval))
  File "/opt/tomigo/virtualenvs/tomigo_core/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 322, in __get__
value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/opt/tomigo/virtualenvs/tomigo_core/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 493, in scheduler
return self.get_scheduler()
 File "/opt/tomigo/virtualenvs/tomigo_core/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 488, in get_scheduler
lazy=lazy)
 File "/opt/tomigo/virtualenvs/tomigo_core/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 53, in instantiate
return symbol_by_name(name)(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/tomigo/virtualenvs/tomigo_core/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 357, in __init__
Scheduler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/tomigo/virtualenvs/tomigo_core/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 184, in __init__
self.setup_schedule()
 File "/opt/tomigo/virtualenvs/tomigo_core/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 376, in setup_schedule
self._store['entries']
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 121, in __getitem__
f = StringIO(self.dict[key])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.py", line 270, in __getitem__
return _DeadlockWrap(lambda: self.db[key])  # self.db[key]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bsddb/dbutils.py", line 68, in DeadlockWrap
return function(*_args, **_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.py", line 270, in <lambda>
return _DeadlockWrap(lambda: self.db[key])  # self.db[key]
DBPageNotFoundError: (-30985, 'DB_PAGE_NOTFOUND: Requested page not found')
```

After an attempt to backup the db I get this error.
I use celery workers and beat for scheduling tasks.
Anyone has any direction how to solve this issue?

Comment: The issue was not resolved there and the post didn't help.

Comment: So you actually *tried* what the answer says there and it did not work? Or are you just *assuming* the answer is worthless because the OP did not accept it? (BTW, the names are the same but I'm a different user than the user who answered there.)